# Jquery auto-click on <span> after page loaded

Tags: jquery

I have a page contains some `<span id="#id">` When I click on each of them , it will run a command using jquery.
Now I want one of this span run that command when page loaded automatically!
Is it possible to do?
I saw the other same questions , but they didn't help me.
thanks

Comment: You can just write into your script on page load to select the span you want the script to execute with, and then do the script.  Or you can logically trigger a click on the element.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the `.trigger()` method.

```
$('span.selector').trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call your function after the page loads like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  yourFunctionExecutedOnSPANclick();
})
```